# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: - Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class:

Tags: java, hibernate

Java 11

Try to use Hibernate

Here migration sql:

```
create table client
(
    id bigserial primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    phone varchar(255)
);
create sequence clientId start 1 NO MAXVALUE;

create table address_data_set
(
    id bigserial primary key,
    street varchar(255) not null,
    client_id bigint not null references client(id)
);
create sequence addressId start 1 NO MAXVALUE;
```

Here entities:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.SEQUENCE;

@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator="clientId_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "clientId_generator", sequenceName = "clientId", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "addresses")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<AddressDataSet> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
}
```

And one more

```
import javax.persistence.*;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.SEQUENCE;

@Entity
@Table(name = "address_data_set")
public class AddressDataSet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator="addressId_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "addressId_generator", sequenceName = "addressId", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", nullable = false)
    private Client client;
}
```

And try run like this:

```
private Main() {
        flywayMigrations();

        var configuration = new Configuration()
                .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect")
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", URL)
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", USER)
                .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", PASSWORD)

                .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
                .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate") 
                .setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");

        var serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        var metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Client.class)
                .getMetadataBuilder()
                .build();

        sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    }

    private void flywayMigrations() {
        logger.info("db migration started...");
        var flyway = Flyway.configure()
                .dataSource(URL, USER, PASSWORD)
                .locations("classpath:/db/migration")
                .load();
        flyway.migrate();
        logger.info("db migration finished.");
        logger.info("***");
    }
```

But I get error:

```
2022-01-13 19:53:45.784 INFO  hw10.Main - db migration started...
2022-01-13 19:53:45.853 INFO  o.f.c.i.license.VersionPrinter - Flyway Community Edition 7.1.1 by Redgate
2022-01-13 19:53:45.984 INFO  o.f.c.i.database.base.DatabaseType - Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5430/hw10 (PostgreSQL 12.9)
2022-01-13 19:53:46.050 INFO  o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate - Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.036s)
2022-01-13 19:53:46.063 INFO  o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Current version of schema "public": 11
2022-01-13 19:53:46.064 INFO  o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
2022-01-13 19:53:46.066 INFO  hw10.Main - db migration finished.
2022-01-13 19:53:46.066 INFO  hw10.Main - ***
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: hw10.model.Client.addresses[hw10.model.AddressDataSet]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1351)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:874)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:799)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1693)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1661)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this block:

```java
    @Column(name = "addresses")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<AddressDataSet> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
```

You either use `@Column` or a`@One/ManyToOne/Many` relation. You cannot use both. The first one is for mapping primitive data types. The other one is for entities relations. Remove `@Column` and you should be good to go.

**Update**

You added `Client` as annotated class, but not `AddressDataSet`. Add it just under the `addAnnotatedClass(Client.class)`:

```java
var metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Client.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(AddressDataSet.class)
                .getMetadataBuilder()
                .build();
```

Comment: @gmajon Not help. Same error

Comment: I updated the answer.